# My props are valued undefined under ComponentDidMount method in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props, react-state

Why my values under `this.props` and `this.state` are undefined in my `componentDidMount` method? In other parts of my class component I can access my props and state values correctly. Do I need to pass them separately to somewhere or where have I made any mistakes?

There I get no values:

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.token)
    console.log(this.state.training.coach)
    // values are null and undefined.
    if (this.props.token == this.state.training.coach) {
        this.setState({
            iscreator: true
        });
        console.log(this.state.iscreator)
    } else {
        this.setState({
            iscreator: false
        });
    }
}
```

There I get correct values when accessing `this.props.token`:

```
handleDelete = (event) => {
    if (this.props.token !== null) {
        const trainingID = this.props.match.params.trainingID;
        axios.defaults.headers = {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Authorization: this.props.token
            }
        axios.delete(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${trainingID}/`)
        this.props.history.push('/');
        this.forceUpdate();
    } else {
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState` is asynchronous, meaning that the function after doesn't wait till it is complete so if you `console.log` your state right after updating it may still have the old value.

To fix this you can check your state value in your `render` where it will eventually update, or you can run a `setState` with a callback like this

```
this.setState({iscreator: true}, () => console.log(this.state.iscreator) )
```

This makes sure to run the `console.log` only after the `setState` is done.

Comment: yes, but why are my this.props.token and this.state.training.coach values undefined?

Comment: Cause it only takes a fraction of time for it to update and by the time you click on the button that calls `handleDelete`  the `setState` has already been completed.

Comment: But when i console those values above setState, they should have something in them. Why are those empty? Or what should i do in order it to work?